# Show that $\sum\nolimits_{d|n} \frac{1}{d} = \frac{\sigma (n)}{n}$ for every positive integer $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, divisor-sum

> Show that $\sum\nolimits_{d|n} \frac{1}{d} = \frac{\sigma (n)}{n}$ for every positive integer $n$.

where $\sigma (n)$ is the sum of all the divisors of $n$
and $\sum\nolimits_{d|n} f(d)$ is the summation of $f$ at each $d$ where $d$ is the divisor of $n$.

I have written $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}p_3^{\alpha_3}.......p_k^{\alpha_k}$ then:-
$$\begin {align*} \sum\nolimits_{d|n} \frac{1}{d}&=\frac{d_2.d_3......d_m+d_1.d_3......d_m+........+d_1.d_2.d_3......d_{m-1}}{d_1.d_2.d_3......d_m}  \\&=\frac{d_2.d_3......d_m+d_1.d_3......d_m+........+d_1.d_2.d_3......d_{m-1}}{p_1^{1+2+...+\alpha_1}p_2^{1+2+...+\alpha_2}p_3^{1+2+....+\alpha_3}.......p_k^{1+2+....+\alpha_k}}  \\ \end{align*}$$
where $d_i$ is some divisor among the $m$ divisors.
Then I cannot comprehend the numerator so that to get the desired result.

Also suggest some other approches to this question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$\displaystyle
n\sum_{d|n} \frac{1}{d} = \sum_{d|n} \frac{n}{d} = \sum_{d|n} {d} = \sigma (n)
$

or

$\displaystyle
\frac{\sigma (n)}{n} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n} {d} =  \sum_{d|n} \frac{d}{n} = \sum_{d|n} \frac{1}{d}
$

Comment: nice answer I was attempting the question from just the opposite direction.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\sigma (n)          &=\sum_{d|n}d (\text{ i.e. sum of all divisors of $n$})\\
                    &=\sum_{d|n}\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) (\text{ i.e. sum of all divisors of $n$})\\
\therefore \sigma(n)&= n\sum_{d|n}\frac{1}{d}\\
\Rightarrow \sum_{d|n}\frac{1}{d}=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Is the sum of all divisors of n divided by n < (1 +1/2+ 1/3+..+ 1/n)/2 ?

Comment: @201044 your statement is incorrect for $n=1$ and $n=360$ and for thirty other values of $n$