# Rigorous proof of $n\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{1}{d}=\sum_{d\mid n}d$ for $n\in\mathbb N$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum

Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and consider the sum

$$\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{n}{d}.$$

I understand that dividing $n$ by any of it's divisors is also a divisor of $n$ so intuitively it would make sense that $\{\frac n d\ :\ d\mid n \}=\{d\ :\ d\mid n\}$, from which the desired equality in the title is acquired. but I cannot "see" how this can be proven rigorously. Any help or insight would be appreciated!

Edit: In many sources, including the question this one is marked as a possible duplicate to, it is not explained *why* the identity holds, it's just used. If it actually is explained, it's not clear to me, at least. I am interested in an actual explanation, that's why my question differs from the one marked as duplicate.

Comment: By definition, $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$.

Comment: This is exactly the same as $\sum_{m=0}^n f(m) = \sum_{m=0}^n f(n-m)$... Do you really need help to "prove it rigorously" ?

Comment: @reuns There is no need to get cocky. I am trying to understand mathematics here. If something does not make sense to me I sometimes want to (see someone) "prove it rigorously", which isn't such a strange thing. I'm sorry but your comment is not at all helpfull, it only made me feel worse about not understanding a thing that apparently is so very clear to everyone. I do understand the equality in your comment, however. Can you specify $f$ so that it makes sense in the context of my question?

Comment: Is it clear to you that $ m \mapsto n-m$ is a bijection $0 \ldots n$ ? Therefore $\sum_{m=0}^n f(m) = \sum_{m=0}^n f(n-m)$. Then $d \mapsto n/d$ is a bijection from the set of divisors of $n$ to itself. Therefore $\sum_{d | n}f(d) = \sum_{d | n}f(n/d)$

Comment: @reuns Thank you for your response. Yes, I do understand the first bijection and the equality that follows from that. However, I do not see how this implies that $d\mapsto\frac n d$ is a bijection from the set of divisors of $n$ to itself. I do see how this implies the final equality, though.

Comment: It doesn't imply it.  It is **obvious** that $d \mapsto n/d$ is a bijection.

Comment: @reuns I think that we have found the source of my problem. The fact that this mapping is a bijection is not at all obvious to me, in the sense that I cannot prove it rigorously (or at all), I only sense intuitively that this would be true. Could you (or anybody else reading this) provide me with a proof or a hint on how to prove this statement?

Comment: @Tyron You proved it yourself in the comments to my post :)

Comment: Let $T(d) = \frac{n}{d}$. If $d\ |\ n$ then $T(d)\ |\ n$ thus the map is well-defined, and $T(T(d)) = d$ thus $T^{-1} $ exists and $T$ is bijective.

Comment: @reuns YES thank you so much! I was looking for some simple prove like this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly the right idea, noting that $d \mid n \iff \frac{n}{d} \mid n$.
$$\begin{align}
n \sum_{d \mid n} \frac{1}{d} &= \sum_{d \mid n} \frac{n}{d} \\
&= \sum_{\frac{n}{d} \mid n} \frac{n}{d} \\
&= \sum_{m \mid n} m \\
&= \sum_{d \mid n} d
\end{align}$$

Comment: Just [lhf's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157419/show-that-sum-nolimits-dn-frac1d-frac-sigma-nn-for-every-pos), indeed.

Comment: Thank you, this answer makes a lot of sense to me. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to convince myself of the second step you make, going from the top line to one below it. Could you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: These two are equivalent, because $d \mid n \iff \frac{n}{d} \mid n$. Can you see why this is true, and why this implies the two lines are equal?

Comment: @B.Mehta Yes I can see why it is true. If $d|n$, then $n=dk$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, which per definition means that $k|n$ and also it follows that $k=\frac n d$. Proving the other direction of implication can be done in a similar fashion. I do not see how this implies that the two lines are equal, however.

Comment: The numbers $d$ for which $d \mid n$ are exactly the numbers $d$ for which $\frac{n}{d} \mid n$. So, the two sums are over exactly the same values, hence are equal.